# Finite product of semilocal rings is semilocal

Tags: commutative-algebra, maximal-and-prime-ideals

We know a ring is *semilocal* if it has finitely many maximal ideals.

> Prove that finite product of semilocal rings is semilocal.

I am trying to prove it but, so far can't having any luck. I am thinking about using the fact is if $R$ is semilocal ring then $R/J(R)$ is product of finite field. Where $J(R)$ is Jacobson radical of the ring. 
Any hint or help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance.

One thing I want to say,  is this question is pretty easy if we consider the  product of our rings to be direct product that is of the form $R_1×R_2$. But what I am having trouble understanding is what if the product they meant in the question is $R_1R_2$ where every elements is of the form $\sum x_iy_i$, with $x_i \in R_1, y_i \in R_2$. So it will be great if someone clarify this topic also.

Answer (score 1):

Consider product of two rings, $ R=R_1×R_2$. Then every prime ideal in $ R$ is of the form $R_1×q$ or $p× R_2$, where $p$ and $q$ are prime ideal of $ R_1$ and $R_2$ respectively.

> First, every ideal in $R$ is of the form  $I×J$, where $I, J$ are ideals of $R_1, R_2$ respectively. In fact, if $\alpha$ is ideal of $R$, then $\alpha=(1,0)\alpha×(0,1)\alpha$.
>
> Second, since $(1,0)(0,1)=(0,0)$, we know every prime ideal in $R$ contains $(1,0)$ or $(0,1)$.

So the result follows.

Comment: Wait they meant direct product by saying normal product. I thought  it meant a product like product of ideals

Comment: @user631697  Can you say this more clearly. I can't understand.

Comment: I thought by seeing the question that product should be something of the form $R_1R_2$, where all elements will be of the form $\sum x_i y_i$ where $x_i \in R_1$ and $y_i \in R_2$.  Not in the way of direct product of $R_1× R_2$

Comment: @user631697 sure. I think you should edit your question again. I misunderstand you question. Is this ture for $R_1R_2$?

Comment: What I have written as question, is the question given in the book that I am solving from. That's why I am also not sure weather they meant it's $R_1R_2$ or $R_1×R_2$. If it's indeed the direct product of semilocal rings, then obviously it's true. But if it's $R_1R_2$ then I am not quite sure about it.

Comment: @user631697 So you should say this clearly in your question. I think the meaning in your book is $R_1xR_2$.